# fixing DKMS, missing modules

Tags: rhel, nvidia, dkms

running RHEL 7.8 with DKMS 2.8.3-2 installed, along with nvidia driver.  I have this

```
dkms status

nvidia, 440.82, 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Missing some built modules!) (WARNING! Missing some built modules!) (WARNING! Missing some built modules!) (WARNING! Missing some built modules!)
nvidia, 440.82, 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64, x86_64: installed (original_module exists) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!) (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

I did a `yum update` this morning and now running kernel `3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64`.

- can someone post a link to the proper DKMS instruction or tutorial website if there is one?
- How can I simply purge everything listed by DKMS and start fresh by reinstalling `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run` and saying yes when prompted to register nvidia with dkms?

  - can i simply do a `rm -r /var/lib/dkms/nvidia` or is that no bueno?
  - tried doing `dkms [remove|uninstall] -m nvidia -v 440.82` with and without `-k` option with no luck.

Comment: What about doing `dkms remove  -m nvidia -v 440.82 --all` and then running the installer again  ?

Comment: it seems dkms has some bugs.  I had to `yum remove dkms` along with `rm -r /var/lib/dkms/nvidia` and then do a `yum install dkms`.  No dkms command resulted in removing the old nvidia in the dkms tree.